# How to call a class method from another class method function?

Tags: python, tkinter, subclass

I'm making a quiz app that involves reading data from a JSON file and storing the user's name and password into an SQL database.

I made 2 classes: one class runs the GUI and the other class handles the quiz logic. How can I call the quiz class into the GUI class from a click of a Tkinter button?

Here is the code below:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import tix 
from tkinter import ttk
import json
import tkinter.messagebox
import sqlite3

# MAIN GUI DESIGN:

class Main:

    def __init__(self):

        self.root = tix.Tk()
        self.root.title("Quiz App")
        self.root.geometry("850x600+500+200")
        self.root.resizable(False,False)

    # FUNCTIONS AND METHODS:

    def frame2to3(self): # THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP CALLING THE CLASS INTO THIS METHOD

        self.frame2.pack_forget()
        self.frame3.pack(fill="both",expand=True)

    def clearfunc1(self):

        self.entry1.delete(0, 'end')
        self.entry2.delete(0, 'end')

    def clearfunc2(self):

        self.entry3.delete(0, 'end')
        self.entry4.delete(0, 'end')

    def close(self):

        if tkinter.messagebox.askyesno("Quiz App","Are you sure you want to exit?") > 0:
            self.root.destroy()
            return

m = Main()



# QUIZ LOGIC:

class Quiz(Main): # THE CLASS I NEED TO CALL 

    def __init__(self):

        self.q_no =0

        self.display_question()

        self.opt_selected = IntVar()

        self.opts = self.radio_buttons()

        self.display_options()
        self.buttons()

        self.data_size = len(question)

        self.correct =0

    def display_result(self):

        wrong_count = self.data_size - self.correct
        correct  = f"Correct: {self.correct}"
        wrong = f"Wrong: {wrong_count}"

        score = int(self.correct/self.data_size*100)
        result = f"Score: {score}%"

        self.show_result = tk.Label(m.frame3(), text=f"{result}\n{correct}\n{Wrong}")

    def check_ans(self,q_no):

        if self.opt_selected.get() == answer[q_no]:

            return True

    def next_btn(self):

        if self.check_ans(self.q_no):

            self.correct += 1
            self.q_no += 1

        if self.q_no == self.data_size:

            self.display_result()

            self.root.destroy()
        else:

            self.display_question()
            self.display_options()

    def buttons(self):

        self.next_btn = tk.Button(m.frame3(), text = "next" , command=self.next_btn)
        self.next_btn.place(x=780,y=550)

        self.exitButton3 = tk.Button(m.frame3(),text="Exit", command = self.close)
        self.exitButton3.place(x=250,y=140)

    def display_options(self):

        val = 0

        self.opt_selected.set(0)

        for option in options[self.q_no]:
            self.opts[val]['text'] = option
            val += 1

    def display_question(self):

        ques_no = tk.Label(m.frame3(), text=question[self.q_no])
        ques_no.place(x=30,y=90)

    def radio_buttons(self):

        q_list =[]

        y_pos = 150

        while len(q_list) < 4:

            radio_btn = tk.Radiobutton(m.frame3(), text = "", variable=self.opt_selected,value = len(q_list)+1)
            q_list.append(radio_btn)

            radio_btn.place(x=100,y=y_pos)

            y_pos += 30

        return q_list

with open('data1.json') as f:
    data1 = json.load(f)

question = (data1['question'])
options = (data1['options'])
answer = (data1[ 'answer'])

q = Quiz()
```

Comment: Since you have made Quiz a subclass of Main, it is unclear why you need separate instances of Main and Quiz at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside removing the strange pattern of subclassing `Main`, as already mentioned by khelwood, you might want to add a parameter `quiz` to the `Main` class `__init__`. You can then store a reference to the `Quiz` instance as an attribute of the `Main` instance. The instantiation it self would be in this order:

```
quiz = Quiz()
main = Main(quiz=quiz)
```

and the `__init__` method:

```
class Main:
    def __init__(self, quiz):
        self._quiz = quiz
        self.root = tix.Tk()
        ...
```

Update:
But as the `Quiz` instance is required during `Main` instantiation, we might switch the order (and the parameters):

```
main = Main()
quiz = Quiz(main=main)
main.quiz = quiz
```

and

```
class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tix.Tk()
        ...
```

and

```
class Quiz:
    def __init__(self, main):
        self._main = main
        ....
```

Comment: Ok thanks, do I still need to pass in Main into the Quiz class like this:

class Quiz(Main):

Comment: That's a misunderstanding. You do not pass anything. You derive the subclass Quiz from the superclass Main. And, indeed, it is not needed here. I suggest you look into some OOP (object-oriented programming) tutorials for more on that.

Comment: Ok, shouldn't it be like => `self.__quiz = quiz` ?

Comment: Oh wait it is a private attribute?

Comment: You can use both in this case. In case of two underscores, the access from outside becomes sightly more difficult because the name is scrambled. In Python they say: "We are all consenting adults here" meaning that the interpreter lets you do more than many compilers but it's up to you not to break stuff. Look here for example: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-October/025932.html

Comment: Sorry but I get these errors when I do the code like how you showed from at the first comment:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  ... line 302, in <module>
    quiz = Quiz()
  ... line 208, in __init__
    self.display_question()
  ... line 275, in display_question
    ques_no = tk.Label(main.frame3, text=question[self.q_no])
NameError: name 'main' is not defined

Comment: I guess I see the problem here: You want to have a reference to your Main in your Quiz instance and vice versa. I think you can defer this design problem to a later code review. For now you change the instantiation order. See my updated answer.

Comment: Yes you're right. I want to have a reference to my main class and the quiz class vice versa. I get this error now: 

quiz = Quiz(main=main)